# TYPO3 v. 10.4 How to change default language to "German" for a fresh installation

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

For a fresh TYPO3 installation using composer the site is pre-configured with English as default language with language id = 0.

But I want to have the German language as default language. What is the recommended way to do this?

My approach was to manually edit in config.yaml:

- Set language id = 0 for german, set language id = 1 for English
- Set typo3Language: default for german, set typo3Language: en for English

but afterwards no pages are found even when I also checked and edited the URLs accordingly.

My edited config.yaml:

```
base: 'https://my.ddev.site/'
languages:
    -   title: English
        enabled: true
        languageId: 1
        base: /en/
        typo3Language: en
        locale: en_US.UTF-8
        iso-639-1: en
        navigationTitle: English
        hreflang: en-us
        direction: ltr
        fallbackType: strict
        fallbacks: ''
        flag: us
        websiteTitle: ''
    -   title: Deutsch
        enabled: true
        base: 'https://my.ddev.site/'
        typo3Language: default
        locale: de_DE.UTF-8
        iso-639-1: de
        websiteTitle: ''
        navigationTitle: Deutsch
        hreflang: de-DE
        direction: ''
        flag: de
        languageId: 0
        rootPageId: 1
        websiteTitle: ''
```

Comment: How is this related to Composer? If it is not, please remove the irrelevant tag

Comment: No, you are right, composer should not have any impact here. Tag has already been removed.

Answer (score 0):

- This is a Yaml file so watch out for spaces
- rootPageId should not be in the language sector
- typo3Language is only for locallang XLIFF files and english should remain the default

That works fine in my enviroment:

```
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    languageId: '0'
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: DE
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ''
    flag: de
    websiteTitle: ''
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_GB.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: EN
    hreflang: en-gb
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: free
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: gb
    languageId: '3'
rootPageId: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My yaml file is indented correctly, it is not correctly displayed in the <code> block here.  So I guess, with respect to languageId, I can change in the yaml file and it has not any reference to another file or database table?!

Comment: languageId:0 is always default, the ohther should also be in dbtable sys_language